# Question mysteriously deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I answered a question earlier today.  It asked something like for an element $g$ of a free group, does there exist a finite-index subgroup of the free group such that g is a basis element of the subgroup.  The author seems to have deleted the question.  I can't seem to find it in my history (but I switch computers frequently and don't remember which one I was using).

Can a moderator locate the deleted question?  One concern of mine is that it would have been a pretty good homework question for an course in geometric group theory.  That's the only real reason I can imagine it being deleted (since it had multiple upvotes when I answered it).

Comment: Do you mean this one?: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252184/finite-index-subgroup-in-which-g-is-one-element-of-a-basis/252185#252185

Comment: Yes, that's the one.  It's a fine question, and I can't think of any reason it would be deleted.

Comment: I flagged it, and also voted to undelete.

Comment: @stefan kohl: Thanks!

Comment: It's now undeleted.

Comment: Great, thanks to everyone!

Comment: You can search for your own deleted posted with the modifier `deleted:1`, so if it was your answer that is a good way to find it (this is a 10k rep thing, though). Also, in your profile there is a link on the Answers tab of recently deleted answers.

Comment: Why was it deleted in the first place, though?

Comment: The same thing has happened to me, both here and on MSE. One suspects the OP deliberately wanted to get rid of the evidence.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I didn't think the asker could unilaterally delete a question that has answers?

Comment: @DavidRicherby : They can't delete questions that have answers with a positive number of upvotes (maybe above a certain threshold, I don't quite remember).  In this case, it was deleted almost immediately after I answered, so before people had a chance to up vote.

Comment: @AndyPutman Oh, OK. That seems a rather undesirable "feature".

Comment: @AndyPutman I think that it should be "with a positive score", not "with a positive number of upvotes" (example: a question with 3 downvotes and 1 upvote has negative score but a positive number of upvotes).